# Parse Cloud beforeSave get request location

Tags: parse-platform

Is it possible to distinguish where the request came from in a Parse beforeSave hook? That is, to tell if the request came from a client or a Parse job from the server?

Answer (score 0):

beforeSave should still have the `request.user` parameter, if I'm not mistaken. If the request came from a client with a signed in user, or if it came from cloud code but you passed a {"sessionToken":} object as the options, it'll contain the user. I'm not sure if also adding `"useMasterKey":true` to the options will override this behavior or not.

If you're worried about *allowing* users to perform the save, you should instead be looking into ACL / CPLs

https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#security-for-user-objects